# Is there a good quality djvu to pdf converter out there?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, djvu

I am trying to convert djvu documents to pdf documents. The documents are books and they need to be batch converted.

All djvu to pdf converters I have used, including the ddjvu utility, a-pdf-2-djvu, online converters and other converters have the problem that text quality is significantly diminished when converting to pdf.

You can notice the same thing when converting djvu to tif.

Answer (score 0):

The [Zebradoc djvu converter](http://zebradoc-djvu-converter.soft32.com/) claims to fix that problem:

> DjVu Converter can reformat raster e-books (e.g. DJVU or PDF) for devices with small screens such as PDA, phones etc. Tool automatically recognizes text and image zones, scales and reflows text and scales images to best fit target screen size.

**References**

- [Zebradoc djvu Converter](http://zebradoc-djvu-converter.soft32.com/)
- [Java DJVU to PDF eBook converter](http://pd4ml.com/djvu.htm)
- [JavaDjvu](http://www.javadjvu.foxtrottechnologies.com/0/8/09/releasenotes/)

Answer (score 0):

if you can live with an online converter the best one is probably the following: https://www.djvu-pdf.com/ since it also supports the conversion of OCR layers.